# What is the advantage of multiple constructors in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have something like:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(s: number);
    constructor(s: string);
    constructor(s: any) {

    }
}
```

What do those first 2 declarations buy me since the third one now allows anything to be passed in. Can the third (actual) one be made private? It looks like private is ignored on a constructor.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious what you tried before posting this question, since the behavior you want is already the behavior that exists. It surely would have been less work to just write `new MyClass(window)` in the Playground and see it was an error? What's your usual exploration process?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh I thought I did and it let me use the "s : any" constructor. But I've also been having trouble with WebStorm not identifying errors so it may have been WebStorm not identifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *implementation signature*, as it's called, is already not visible. You don't have to do anything to make it 'private'. Whenever a function or constructor is overloaded, only the overloads are seen by callers.

```
var x = new MyClass({n: 3}); // This is an error.
```